# get VCard Avatar iq packet from server SMACK Android XMPP

Tags: android, xmpp, smack

I am sending IQ packet to server properly but unable to get IQ packet from server after comparing hash codes

```
    IQ iq = new IQ(){
            @Override
       public String getChildElementXML() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;    
        }

        };
    iq.setTo(from+"/"+resource);
    iq.setFrom(to);
    iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
    iq.setId("vc2");
    mConnection.sendPacket(iq);
```

I used  vcard.save(mConnection);
I want to retrieve avatar as xep-0153

In receive packet i am getting `<stream></stream>` tag

Answer (score 0):

You are just sending an empty IQ stanza of the type 'Get' with the id 'vc2' to the server.

In order to get a XEP-0054 based VCard you could use [`VCard.load(Connection, String)`](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/3.2.2/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smackx/packet/VCard.html#load%28org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection,%20java.lang.String%29)

.

Comment: is it possible to get the image as a url?

Answer (score 0):

```
IQ iq = new IQ(){
        @Override
   public String getChildElementXML() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;    
    }

    };
iq.setTo(from+"/"+resource);
iq.setFrom(to);
iq.setType(IQ.Type.GET);
iq.setPacketID("vc2");
mConnection.sendPacket(iq);
```

IQ request for xep-0153. we have to setPacketID but not setId